# Restrict blur event when use enter key event

Tags: jquery

I have bind keyup event and blur event to one object.
Enter key is working fine. But as soon as focus lost then unnecessary blur event is firing. How can i restrict blur event when i use keyup event.

Actually i need to do same operation on keyup event and blur event. User will set something either by entering or by just focus out.

Here is my example.

```
$('.classname').on({
    keyup: function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            //Some Code
        }
    },
    blur: function (e) {
       //Some code
    }
});
```

Comment: Bdw what do you have in your blur event and do you want to avoid it only during enter key is pressed??

Comment: yes restrict blur on enter key press..

Comment: normally it happens right?? when you press `enter` only if you specify it the `blur` will happen right??

Answer (score 1):

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/pus7f3bp/)

```js
var enterKeyPressed = false;
$('.classname').on({
  keyup: function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      //Some Code
      enterKeyPressed = true;
      console.log('Enter key');
    }
  },
  blur: function(e) {
    if (enterKeyPressed) {
      //Some code
      enterKeyPressed = false;
    }
    console.log('Blur');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="classname" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the handler functions if they are the same. That can be done as follows. And use the event.stopImmediatePropogation()( referred by @Gurupasad Rao in his comment) inside this common function:

```
$(".classname").bind('blur keyup', function(e){
// Stuff that your function does... 
if(enterKeyPressed){ 
   e.stopImmediatePropogation();
  }
});
```

Comment: Functions are same but should be fire when press enter so combining event is feasible?

Comment: Yes, when enter key pressed, you can stop the immediate propogation. Check the edited answer, where the code now is clear.